# How to add Type Annotations to dataclass with Generic type in Python?

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting

I'm writing a `dataclass` in Python to collect the arguments that `ArgumentParser.add_argument` needs, but I have troubles with the type annotations.

A simplified version:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, KW_ONLY
from typing import Optional, TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")

@dataclass
class CommandLineArgument(Generic[T]):
    name_or_flags: str | tuple[str]
    _: KW_ONLY
    metavar: Optional[str] = None
    type: Optional[type[T]] = None
    default: Optional[T] = None
```

While `mypy` thinks this is correct (no issues found), `pytest` thinks it is not right.
Notice that this happens when I import the `CommandLineArgument` in the test file.

If this class is correctly annotated, why `pytest` complains?

If I change the class to:

```py
@dataclass
class CommandLineArgument(Generic[T]):
    name_or_flags: str | tuple[str]
    _: KW_ONLY
    metavar: Optional[str] = None
    type: Optional[type[T]] = type
    default: Optional[T] = None
```

then `pytest` is happy, but obviously `mypy` is not.

Other variations didn't work with similar problems.

Is there a way to make both `pytest` and `mypy` happy about this?

### Edit:

#### Output of pytest

With simply this `test_cli.py` file:

```py
from cli import CommandLineArgument
```

`pytest` gives the follwoing error:

```
pytest test_cli.py
...

test_cli.py:1: in <module>
    from cli import CommandLineArgument
cli.py:15: in <module>
    class CommandLineArgument(Generic[T]):
cli.py:20: in CommandLineArgument
    type: Optional[type[T]] = None
E   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
...
ERROR test_cli.py - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
...
Interrupted: 1 error during collection
```

Comment: What error does `pytest` report? [mcve], please.

Comment: "pytest thinks it is not right" what does this mean, exactly?

Comment: If you have found an answer that works for you, please click the tick to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you, I added the error reported by pytest and ticked the mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of your module to stop evaluating type annotations at runtime.

---

Here's your minimum reproducible example:

```py
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar("T")

class A(t.Generic[T]):
    type: type[T] | None = None
```

This will fail at runtime, because Python will assign `type = None` inside the body of `A`, then try to evaluate `type[T]` (which becomes `None[T]`) at runtime, with the following failure:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Note that this isn't a pytest or `@dataclass` issue - running the example **normally** will cause this failure.

Comment: That made it!!! Thanks a lot!